# Pin application shortcuts to taskbar

Tags: taskbar

I want to pin several applications to taskbar by a batch file in Windows 10 (as well as Windows 11). I got the codes from web but not work. Please help to modify them to make them work.

PIN.VBS

```
' ### NOTES

' *** Usage - Pin.vbs

' *** WScript.exe "%~dp0\%~dp0\Pin.vbs" [drive:][path]filename [Argument]

' *** [Arguments] = 0 1 2

' *** 0 = Unpin from Taskbar

' *** 1 = Pin to Taskbar

' *** 2 = Install

' *** <no> = List all Verbs

 Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
 Set filesystem = CreateObject("scripting.Filesystemobject")
 If filesystem.FileExists(Wscript.Arguments(0)) Then
  Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(filesystem.GetParentFolderName(Wscript.Arguments(0)))
  Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(filesystem.GetFileName(WScript.Arguments(0)))
  Set colVerbs = objFolderItem.Verbs
  
  If WScript.Arguments.Length = 1 Then
   For Each objVerb in colVerbs
    WScript.Echo Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "")
   Next
  ElseIf WScript.Arguments.Length > 1 Then
   Select case WScript.Arguments(1)
    case 0
     For Each objVerb in colVerbs
      If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Unpin from Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
     Next
    case 1
     For Each objVerb in colVerbs
      If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Pin to Taskbar" Then objVerb.DoIt
     Next
    case 2
     For Each objVerb in colVerbs
      If Replace(objVerb.name, "&", "") = "Install" Then objVerb.DoIt
     Next
   End Select
  End If
 End If
```

BATCH

```
@echo off
%~d0
cd %~d0%~p0

WScript.exe "%~dp0Pin.vbs" "%programfiles%\PDFCreator\PDFCreator.exe" 1

WScript.exe "%~dp0Pin.vbs" "%programfiles%\Macrium\Reflect\Reflect.exe" 1

WScript.exe "%~dp0Pin.vbs" "%programfiles(x86)%\Adobe\Acrobat DC\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe" 1
```

Comment: It depends on the shortcut. Numerous shortcuts will not pin to Task Bar. Some will. Windows 11 Design.

Answer (score 0):

#### Please help to modify them to make them work

It's no longer possible:

> How-to: VBScript to Pin or UnPin items to the Start Menu (Windows 10)
> Executable files on the local machine may be Pinned to the Start Menu and/or Taskbar.
> **In the latest versions of Windows 10, this can no longer be done by invoking the pin/unpin verb in VBScript.**
> An alternative is to use the TechnoSys utility [PinToTaskbar](https://www.technosys.net/products/utils/pintotaskbar) which can pin executables, but not batch files or metro apps to the Start Menu or Task bar for the current user. The utility works by impersonating the Explorer.exe process, but it also temporarily changes the prompt color to green.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

Source [Pin to Start Menu - VBScript - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/vb/syntax-pin.html)

Comment: What other options if I do not want to use the application ?

Comment: @VB88 I've no idea.